# limit displayed static blocks in magento admin

Tags: magento, backend

I would like **to limit the displayed static blocks in the magento admin (`CMS/Static Blocks`**).

A backend user belonging to the vendor group should only be able to see the blocks that he created.

Has anybody succeed at doing something similar?

Thanks